# How to use isArray() in Angular 2+ template?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this variable named `records`,

Now I want to check if its an array or not in angular2/typescript?

In AngularJS I used to do Following:

```
ng-if="selectedCol.data && !isArray(selectedCol.data)"
```

But When I am trying to do the Following its not working;

```
*ngIf="selectedCol.model.data && !Array.isArray(selectedCol.model.data)"
```

Its giving me below error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'isArray' of undefined
>   any inputs?

Answer (score 32):

Angular 2 template is executed inside `Component`'s context, meaning, you can only access properties/methods defined inside `Component`

Simplest way is to define `isArray` method in your `Component`

```
isArray(obj : any ) {
   return Array.isArray(obj)
}
```

In template

```
*ngIf="isArray(selectedCol.model.data)"
```

*To avoid boilerplate code, define Service with `isArray` method, register as Singleton, inject into `Component` and use `isArray` method via Service property*

**Alternatively**, define `_array` property in your `Component` and assign `Array` type to it

```
  private _array = Array;
```

In template

```
*ngIf="_array.isArray(selectedCol.model.data)"
```

Comment: Are we allowed to use private variables in templates ? Template do not exist within component class but outside the component class.

Answer (score 11):

While not being the most efficient solution (see the other answer), `[].constructor.isArray` is suitable for any expression context and doesn't require to contaminate component classes with language-level helpers:

```
*ngIf="selectedCol.model.data && [].constructor.isArray(selectedCol.model.data)"
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what @tchelidze said:

Angular 2 provides a wrapper called `isArray` in [`facade/lang`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ce5b37239ec4214ef1db1a460c71056ec5135489/modules/%40angular/facade/src/lang.ts#L155) exported and defined like this:

```
export function isArray(obj: any): boolean {
  return Array.isArray(obj);
}
```

You can import it into your component like this:

```
import {isArray} from '@angular/facade/lang';
```

Then you could expose it publicly in your component:

`this.isArray = isArray`

And use in your template like so:

`*ng-if="selectedCol.data && !isArray(selectedCol.data)"`

Answer (score 2):

Angular way: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

**is-array.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'isArray' })
export class IsArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: unknown): boolean {
      return Array.isArray(value);
  }
}
```

**my.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="selectedCol.model.data | isArray">...</div>
```